# Retrieving Celery task kwargs from task-failed / uuid

Tags: celery, celery-task

### Main Issue

I'm testing how to handle certain task failure, for example handling a 'TimeLimitExceeded' exception which instantly kills the task and is not 'catchable' (Yes...I'm aware of the existence of 'SoftTimeLimit' but it doesn't fit my needs).

#### First Approach

This is my `tasks.py` (The worker runs with a `--time-limit` flag):

```py
import logging
from celery import Celery
import time


app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

def my_fail(task, exc, req_id, req_args, req_kwargs, einfo, *ext_args, **kwargs):
    logger.info("args: %r", req_args)
    logger.info("kw: %r", req_kwargs)

@app.task(on_failure=my_fail)
def sum(x, y, delay=0, **kw):
    result = x+y
    if result == 4:
        raise Exception("Some Error")
    time.sleep(delay)                                                               
    return x+y
```

The main idea when a task fails, to be able to perform some handling based on the args/kwargs of the task

For example if I run `sum.delay(3, 1, foo="bar")` the `Exception("Some Error")` is raised and the following is logged:

```
[2019-06-30 17:21:45,120: INFO/Worker-1] args: (3, 1)
[2019-06-30 17:21:45,121: INFO/Worker-1] kw: {'foo': 'bar'}
[2019-06-30 17:21:45,122: ERROR/MainProcess] Task tasks.sum[9e9de032-1469-44e7-8932-4c490fcee2e3] raised unexpected: Exception('Some Error',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/apernin/.virtualenvs/dr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/apernin/.virtualenvs/dr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/apernin/test/tasks.py", line 89, in sum
    raise Exception("Some Error")
Exception: Some Error
```

Note the args/kwargs are printed by my `on-failure` handler.

Now if I run `sum.delay(3, 2, delay=7)` the **TimeLimit** is triggered

```
[2019-06-30 17:23:15,244: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.sum[8c81398b-4378-401d-a674-a3bd3418ccde]
[2019-06-30 17:23:21,070: ERROR/MainProcess] Task tasks.sum[8c81398b-4378-401d-a674-a3bd3418ccde] raised unexpected: TimeLimitExceeded(5.0,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/apernin/.virtualenvs/dr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 645, in on_hard_timeout
    raise TimeLimitExceeded(job._timeout)
TimeLimitExceeded: TimeLimitExceeded(5.0,)
[2019-06-30 17:23:21,071: ERROR/MainProcess] Hard time limit (5.0s) exceeded for tasks.sum[8c81398b-4378-401d-a674-a3bd3418ccde]
[2019-06-30 17:23:21,629: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-1' pid:15472 exited with 'signal 15 (SIGTERM)'
```

Note the args/kwargs are note printed, because of the `on-failure` handler not being excuted. This is somewhat to be expected due to the nature of Celery's Hard Time Limit.

#### Second Approach

My second approach is to use a event-listener.

```py
from celery import Celery


def my_monitor(app):
    state = app.events.State()

    def announce_failed_tasks(event):
        state.event(event)
        # task name is sent only with -received event, and state
        # will keep track of this for us.
        task = state.tasks.get(event['uuid'])

    with app.connection() as connection:
        recv = app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={
                'task-failed': announce_failed_tasks,
        })
        recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Celery(broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
    my_monitor(app)
```

The only info I was able to retrieve was the task **uuid**, I wasn't able to retrieve the name, args or kwargs of the task (the task object contains the attributes but are all None).

#### Question

Is there a way to either:

- Make the `on_failure` handler in case of a Hard Time Limit?
- Retrieve the tasks args/kwargs of a task with a `task-failed` event listener?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the timeout is handled by the Worker (the MainProcess) and it is not treated the same as failures happened INSIDE the task, such as exceptions being thrown, etc. This is why you see it as TimeLimitExceeded raised by the MainProcess in the log. So, unfortunately you can't rely on the same logic...

However, your second approach will prove useful in tracking down what is going on.

I have developed (in-house) a Celery monitoring tool that grabs all the events, and populates a database with them so that later we can do all sort of analytics (see average and worst running times for an example, frequency of failures, etc).

In order to grab the details you need from the data given by the `task-failed` event you also need to record (store it in some dictionary for an example) the `task-received` event data. This information contains args, task names, and all sort of useful information you may need. You relate them both by the task UUID.

Comment: Thanks, I had already started developing based on the second approach but was hoping there was another possibility. One last question, your "listener", do you have it running like a standalone Python or is there a "celery worker" way to run it?
Thanks for the help

Comment: It is a stand-alone service which runs as a regular systemd service.